# C++ macro ignoring what's after

Tags: c++, macros

I was working on a dynamic programming problem and decided not to use the std::max function as I figured that a macro would be quicker(no pushing arguments on stack, not templated).

But it is not working exactly as expected. I have isolated the issue and it looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#define maxi(a, b) (a <= b)? b : a

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    c =  maxi(a, b) + 1;
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

While it is indeed returning the maximum, it seems to ignore the addition of 1 after that. In this example the value of c ends up being 0 while I'd expect it to be 1. Why is that?

Comment: Your expression is going to expand to `c = (a <= b)? b : a + 1;`

Comment: Spoiler alert: compilers have been inlining function calls just fine for decades.

Comment: Note that this macro will evaluate one of its arguments twice. To see that, try this: `int f() { std::cout << "f\n"; return 0; } int g() { std::cout << "g\n"; return 1; } maxi(f(), g());`.

Comment: That macro will produce the "correct" result for `maxi(2,1)`. <g>

Comment: Reason #722 for not using macros.

Answer (score 3):

Your code after macro substitution will look as follows. Do you see now where's the mistake?

```
// ...
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
c =  (a <= b)? b : a + 1;
```

To make a quick fix just put all your macro into additional () as `#define maxi(a, b) ((a <= b)? b : a)`. That's a good practice when you write any macro. That change will result in the following change in code:

```
// ...
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
c =  ((a <= b)? b : a) + 1;
```

Just bear in mind that if your a and b parameters are more complex, you will wind up with similar issue, therefore to make macro even more error prone you should put all the parameters in separate () too, as in `#define maxi(a, b) (((a) <= (b))? (b) : (a))`

Comment: Thank you! this answers it.

Answer (score 1):

Your macro is missing multiple parentheses to avoid it breaking in certain expressions, e.g. in your shown case it will be replace to:

```
    c =  (a <= b)? b : a + 1;
```

and as you can see you will return either `b` or `a+1`. That is not what you intended.

You need to write the macro as

```
#define maxi(a, b) (((a) <= (b)) ? (b) : (a))
```

to avoid such and similar issues in the arguments.

This is not in any way more efficient than `std::max`. Compilers do inline small functions and after inlining, the function using `std::max` will look pretty much the same as if `maxi` was substituted. There will be no passing of function arguments, whether in registers or on the stack.

Btw. a function being templated or not has no impact on its performance characteristics. So I don't know why you mention that in the question.

And as you can see macros are a lot harder to work with, so there is no reason to use them.

On contrary, your macro will be *worse* in some situations, e.g.:

```
maxi(f(a), f(b))
```

where `f` is some function, will substitute to (roughly)

```
(f(a) <= f(b))? f(b) : f(a);
```

meaning that `f` will always be evaluated *three* times, for the first two calls in the comparison and once for the chosen branch.

On the other hand `std::max(f(a), f(b))` evaluates `f` only *twice*.

This means the macro will not only take more time, it will also possibly have unintended effects if the function calls have side effects.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ pre - processor replaces the words before compilation 
So your line becomes -

```
c = (a<=b) ? b : a +1;
```

Which only increments `a` when `a>b`

For doing both the code `#define` segment should be curled with braces generally to remove ambiguity -

```
#define maxi(a, b) ((a <= b)? b : a)
```

This would make the pre processed line as

```
c = ((a<=b) ? b : a) +1;
```

Which will generate the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

> I was working on a dynamic programming problem and decided not to use the std::max function as I figured that a macro would be quicker(no pushing arguments on stack, not templated).

Your decision is not very wise. Any half decent optimizing compiler will optimize out the function call in `std::max`. Macros just poison anything they are involved in, as can be seen from your example.

---

To see what's wrong with your macro, tell your compiler to show you the preprocessed version of your source code (`-E` flag for GCC):

This:

```
#define maxi(a, b) (a <= b)? b : a

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    c =  maxi(a, b) + 1;
}
```

Turns into this:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    c = (a <= b)? b : a + 1;
}
```

Which is not what you wanted. Here is the "Fix":

```
#define maxi(a, b) (((a) <= (b))? (b) : (a))
```

This is really not a real solution. Consider something like this `maxi(++a, b)`. That expands to `(((++a) <= (b))? (b) : (++a))` which potentially increments `a` twice. This is definitely not the expected behavior.

Comment: It is less that a compiler "optimises it out", and more that it just doesn't generate an unnecessary function call in the first place. It interprets what the program described by your code _means_, then produces an optimal computer program with the same meaning. It doesn't just go line-by-line through your code converting it into another language.

Comment: In my experience I got noticeably different times with inlined functions/macros than regular functions on coding sites, so perhaps they do not optimize on purpose.

Comment: Don't know what those "coding sites" are, but if they're using `-O0` (a "go into a mode where we _do_ just line-by-line convert your code so that you can debug it more easily" feature) then they're not really testing anything real.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings that is very correct. The key point is, the compiler does not generate your program in a different language. It generates a similar program which has the same observable behavior.

Comment: Spot on :) Might sound like nitpicking, or an academic distinction, but I genuinely believe that understanding this is key to understanding why, for example, writing programs with undefined behaviour is such a bad idea, even if you think "it's just a memory location".